# Entity reference option limit refering a limited field

Tags: entities

This is what I try to do:
I have a "master structure" built in taxonomy: 
Vocabulary A: careers
Vocabulary B: courses, related to careers by a term reference field.

I have schools as nodes. "school" is a content type.
Each school must have the same master structure copied as nodes. Some schools have all careers, some have less. In each school the course structure for a career can differ.

So I created two content types: careers for schools and courses for schools. When a school is created the master structure will be copied to be modified after.

The "career for schools" content type has an entity reference field to the career taxonomy and an entity reference field to the school.

The "courses for schools" content type has an entity reference field to the school, and a "career" entity reference field to the *career content type* limited to the careers defined for the school. So far, it works.

Now for the course field I want to display only the courses in the school vocabulary that have the career I chose in the career field. But the field is not listed in the option limit settings because there is no matching field.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.